Manometer with asymmetry

I have recently been learning about Fluid, and got stumped about a concept of it. From my textbook, it states that the pressure of the points at the same depth are always equal to each other as in manometer. The textbook also says that if the pressures are not equal to each other, then the fluid in manometer will eventually be accelerated. I totally agree with this statement but only when the manometer has the same cross-sectional area. If I follow the same logic as my textbook said, how can $P_a = P_b$ [in the picture]? Because
if I consider a system to be a fluid in the tube, the force exerted by $P_a$ [let's say $F_a$] is $F_a = P_a A_1$ and the force exerted by $P_b$ [let's say $F_b$] is $F_b = P_b A_2$. 
$A_1$ is cross-sectional area on the left side of the tube, and $A_2$ is cross-sectional area on the right side of the tube. It can be clearly seen that if $P_a = P_b$ then the force $F_a$ will surely not be equal to $F_b$ [so the fluid will be accelerated]. So how can $P_a = P_b$ in this situation? I am not certain that the logic about the net force will be appliable or not. So feel free to answer :).

Stevino's law and pressure in static fluid. Before discussing about your intuition, I'm giving you the physical law that governs pressure distribution in fluids at rest, Stevino's law,
$$dP = -\rho \, g \, dz \ .$$
assuming $\mathbf{g}$ is the gravitational field, nearly uniform in a limited region of space, and in direction $-\hat{\mathbf{z}}$. For fluid with uniform density - and you can usually model water as a constant density fluid with $\rho = \overline{\rho} = 1000 \, kg/m^3$ -, you can easily integrate the differential form of Stevino's law to get
$$P_0 - P_1 = -\overline{\rho} g (z_0 - z_1) \ ,$$
being $0$, $1$ the indices referring to 2 points in the fluid, at different heights $z$ over a horizontal reference line. From this law, you can easily see that if $z_0 = z_1$ then $P_0 = P_1$, and thus 2 points in the same fluid at the same height have the same pressure.
Integral balance. The intuition about the force acting on the fluid is a good intuition, leading to the integral form of the equilibrium equation.
Anyway, the logic is wrong since it doesn't take into account 2 contributions:

the weight of the water
the force acting on the water due to the interaction with solid walls of the U-pipe.

Since you miss these 2 contributions, the conclusions you draw are wrong. The right way to write the integral balance is
$$\mathbf{0} = \mathbf{F}^{tot} = \sum_i \mathbf{F}^v_i + \sum_j \mathbf{F}^s_j \ ,$$
being $\mathbf{F}^{tot}$ the sum of the forces acting on the volume, both "volume forces" $\mathbf{F}^v_i$ and "surface forces" $\mathbf{F}^s_j$. Volume force comes from the weight of the fluid,
$$\sum_i \mathbf{F}^v_i = - \rho g V \hat{\mathbf{z}} = - mg \hat{\mathbf{z}} \ ,$$
while surface forces from the contact of the boundary of the fluid volume with both solid walls and air at the 2 free surfaces, and reading
$$\sum_j \mathbf{F}^s_j = - P_a A_a \hat{\mathbf{z}} - P_b A_b \hat{\mathbf{z}} + \mathbf{F}^s_{walls} \ .$$
Thus, the right way to write the integral balance of forces is
$$\mathbf{0} = - mg \hat{\mathbf{z}}  - P_a A_a \hat{\mathbf{z}} - P_b A_b \hat{\mathbf{z}} + \mathbf{F}^s_{walls} \ .$$
Remarks.

If you don't know the term $\mathbf{F}^s_{walls}$ this equation can't provide $P_a$ nor $P_b$;

In order to evaluate $\mathbf{F}^s_{walls}$, you usually need to evaluate pressure field $P(\mathbf{r}_{wall})$ at the solid walls using Stevino's law, and then integrate all the contributions,
$$\mathbf{F}^s_{wall} = \int_{S_{wall}} P \hat{\mathbf{n}} \ ,$$
assuming the geometry and thus the unit normal vector $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is known.

Pressure at free surface in open environment in the layout of your system of interest is atmospheric pressure, $P_{atm}$; if you know it and the mass (and thus the weight) of the fluid, you can use the integral balance to evaluate $\mathbf{F}^s_{wall}$ as
$$\mathbf{F}^s_{wall} = mg \hat{\mathbf{z}} + P_a A_a \hat{\mathbf{z}} + P_b A_b \hat{\mathbf{z}} $$



Below I have drawn a sketch of the fluid in a simplified U-tube manometer and the vertical forces acting on it.

The two forces at the top are produced by the external pressures exerted on the fluid at the open ends of the manometer and you are correct in saying that $F_{\rm B}>F_{\rm A}$.
However as you can see from my diagram, the walls of the manometer also exert vertical forces on the fluid, $F_{\rm D}$ and $F_{\rm E}$.
At equilibrium the vertical forces acting on the fluid add up to zero.
Thus with down positive, $F_{\rm A}+F_{\rm B}+F_{\rm D}-F_{\rm E}=0$.
